# Make Python conclusively read a package from a local directory

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

If I install all packages using

```
python setup.py install --prefix=~/.local
```

how can I make Python read my packages from there and not from the system wide version? I tried editing `PYTHONPATH` to put `~/.local/lib/python2.x/site-packages/` first, but it does not help.

I thought that `~/.local` is guaranteed to be read first in Python 2.6 and later versions. Is this true? Is something special required to make it true? That would solve the issue. Right now it seems that `PYTHONPATH` paths get incorporated into `sys.path` but are in the list after the system-wide `site-packages` directories, making the system wide version get used instead of the one in `~/.local`.

Using `pip` is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: try doing `import os;print os.environ['PYTHONPATH'];` and make sure the path you want is included

Comment: They are in there, but are ignored.

Comment: A similar setup works fine on my Ubuntu box, without doing any manipulation of `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`. Importing the `sys` module in a Python shell I can see that the user installation appears before than the local and the system installations in the sys.path list. If that is your case and you can't import modules from your user installation maybe you should double check that your installation is correct: all modules/packages are actually there, required `__init__.py` are present and everything has proper permissions.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that you use `virtualenv` with a proper activation script which will take care of settings up PYTHONPATH properly, without messing up system-wide Python installation in any way

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html